# Find the inverse and domain of a function $f(x)= \sqrt{x+1}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I know the inverse is $x^2-1$.

The range of $f(x)= \sqrt{x+1}$ is $[0,\infty)$ and isn't the range of a function the domain of its inverse, so means the domain of $f^{-1}(x)=x^2-1$ is $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: $x+1\ge0$ as the square root cannot have negative inputs and have a real output.

Comment: $[-1,\infty) $ is domain.

Comment: It looks like you may be confusing the domain and range of the function or the domain of the function with the domain of its inverse.  Please edit your question to explain how you obtained those two possible answers for the domain of the function.

Comment: I edited your typesetting so it reads better. With your math edits it is correct now. The function $g(x)=x^2-1$ has domain equal to $\mathbb{R}$ when there are no other restrictions, but as the inverse of $f(x)$ the domain you state is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Given the original function, we can get the inverse as follows:

$f(x) = \sqrt{x + 1} \\
\text{Let } y = f(x) \\
y = \sqrt{x + 1} \\
\text{To inverse...} \\
x = \sqrt{y + 1} \\
x^2 = y + 1 \\
y = x^2 - 1 \\
f^{-1}(x) = x^2 - 1$

You've already gotten to this step, however, we need to consider the domain and range of the original function. The domain of the original function is $[-1, \infty)$ and the range is $[0, \infty)$.

Visualizing an inverse of a function, it's just the original but reflected over the line $y=x$. The domain of the original becomes the range of the inverse, and vice-versa.

Switching the domains and ranges would look something like this:

$f(x) = \sqrt{x+1}, \text{ D:}[-1, \infty) \text{ R:}[0, \infty) \\
f^{-1}(x) = x^2 - 1, \text{ D:}[0, \infty) \text{ R:}[-1, \infty)$

You have to blindly switch the domain and range in order for the function to be the actual inverse. Even though the domain of $y = x^2 - 1$ is $(-\infty, \infty)$, you have to restrict it to $[0, \infty)$.